# Showing that the absolute value of |X| converges almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Here is my question and my solutions. I am just curious if this makes sense.
[image: Q2 and A2]

If something is wrong, then it will be nice if you can correct it for me or provide another solution. Please and thank you!

Comment: It is fine, but there is a simpler answer, if $A=[X >10]$ has positive measure, then $A_m=[X > 10+{1 \over m}]$ has positive measure for some $n$. Then $|X-X_n| \ge {1 \over m}$ on $A_m$ which contradicts convergence in probability.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that information. I am guessing it has to do with measure theory. What I have learned so far never really covered this.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on copper.hats comment, if $\mathbb P(X>10)>0$ then there exists some integer $m$ such that $\mathbb P\left(X>10+\frac1m\right)$. But this implies that $\mathbb P\left(|X-X_m|\geqslant \frac1m\right)$, and contradicting the assumption that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(|X-X_n|\geqslant \frac1n\right) = 0.
$$